# Openshift File Uploading in Java

Tags: java, file-upload, openshift

I am doing a program to file-uplaod in the openshift. In this program I am upload whole files documents in the uploads folder, which is given default folder of the Openshift server.
I am using the file upload path

> System.getenv("OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR")

for upload files.

But **I want to upload the file in my own project folder**. I am created folder externally and I want to all the file in this folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR is the correct location for persistent data.  If you upload to your $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR, subsequent git pushes will overwrite contents of with your local repo and the uploads will be lost.

If I'm misunderstanding your use case, please help me understand the reference to 'project folder' and 'created folder externally'.  Feel free to share your use case on the OpenShift Forums as well:  https://www.openshift.com/forums/openshift

Comment: $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR - I had already used this but not working.. folder not found some kind of exception throw.... Any another solution you have please share with me...